How can I add mix arbitrary text in the output of the Linux date command?
I used this command in some of my scripts which echo date +%Y%m%d_%H%M which outputs a date of the kind 20241231_0438 but sometimes I want the output to go a source code file meaning I have to prefix it with the language's comment syntax, eg // .
How can I put arbitrary text in the date format text?
I have some luck using date +##%Y%m%d_%H%M to make it a comment in some conf files, but I need some kind of general formula.

date +"// %Y%m%d_%H%M"
date +"# %Y%m%d_%H%M"

And I very much doubt that echo date +%Y%m%d_%H%M generates anything other than:
date +%Y%m%d_%H%M


You mean the wrapping in double quotes makes the difference?

@vfclists It does for me if you're asking about the output of e.g. a literal // or # ...  ubuntu 20.04, bash 5.0.17, date 8.30 ..
